# How to select all textures used by all active materials in the scene?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a project in my hands that has one object mesh (a city block with buildings) with around 10K materials that each have a texture in them. The textures for these material slots themselves are in their own folder.

I wanted to take a small piece of that city block (still with around 500 materials) and put it all into a neat package with only active materials and needed textures.

Cutting the piece out of the city into its own file and With the help of Materials Utils Add-on I was able to delete the unused materials.

But how could I round up the used textures? From that folder of some 10K images I somehow need to pick out the ones that are in active use in the materials. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you save then reload your file, Blender will get rid of the unlinked (unused) images. (and Materials, by the way)

Then you can use **File/External Data/Pack all into file**, you should end up with a .blend that contain every image used in the scene.

If you need to keep them as separated files, you can copy your packed .blend in a different folder, then use **External Data/Unpack all into files**.